# can't use send images in functions in discord bot in cogs

Tags: python, discord, bots

for some reason it seems that i cant send images with this

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
     if str(message.content).lower == "pic" :
         await message.send("text", file=discord.File('picture.png'))
```

i thougth the problem was in the function on_message itself
after i saw the documenttion i figured out that i can send it only with

```
channel.send(file=discord.file('pic.png'))
```

so i tried this

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
     channel = self.client.get_channel("channel id")
     if str(message.content).lower == "pic" :
         await channel.send("text", file=discord.File('picture.png'))
```

didn't work as i thoght

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, when checking if the lowercase version of the message content is equal to "pic," you need to call the lower() method to convert it to lowercase. Currently, you're missing the parentheses, so the comparison won't work correctly. Modify the condition to str(message.content).lower() == "pic".

> Second, when sending a message with a file attachment, you should use the await message.channel.send() method instead of await message.send(). Adjust your code to use await message.channel.send("text", file=discord.File('picture.png')).

**Here is the Fixed version of your code !:**

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if str(message.content).lower() == "pic":
        await message.channel.send("text", file=discord.File('picture.png'))
```

try it and tell me.

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).